# tips for installing postgres for a rails project on a linux box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, postgresql

I want to use a postgres database for 2 rails projects and for some php blogs. Does anybody have tips for me, which pg gem I should install for ruby? 
I'm searching also for some general postgres config tips.

I run Ubuntu 9.04 as Server.

Maybe a (not outdated) good tutorial would be great :)

thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/database-support/postgres) from the Rails wiki should contain the information you are looking for.

I suggest you to install the `pg` GEM:

```
gem install pg
```

Also, Slicehost published a really interesting collection of article about using and configuring PostgreSQL on Ubuntu: http://articles.slicehost.com/postgresql

Answer (score 1):

gem to install is ruby-pg

[Tutorial for 8.04](http://hocuspokus.net/2008/05/install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-804)

[Tutorial for 9.04 LAMP with Postgres](http://www2.russbrooks.com:8000/2009/5/25/install-ubuntu-9-04-server-edition-rails-php-passenger-postgresql-and-mysql)

Comment: Installation is simple - if you only use the local machine for your rails apps you won;t need to change access config.