# How to install BBYIDX on Windows?

Tags: installation, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I do not know anything about Ruby still I would like to install [BBYIDX](https://github.com/BBYOpen/BBYIDX) on my clean Windows 7 machine.

If you don't know how to install this special website at least describe me how to run a Ruby on Rails web application from scratch please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Install Postgres**

You can download Postgres from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/)

**Launch `pgadmin` tool**

- Create a user called `bbyidx` (with password `bbyidx`) with admin privileges.
- Create a database called `bbyidx_dev`.

**Install `ruby`**

[Download](http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75679/rubyinstaller-1.8.7-p357.exe) and install Ruby.

**Install ruby dev kit**

- [Download](http://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20110712-1620-sfx.exe) and install the dev kit.
- When installing the Development Kit, type `C:\RubyDevKit` in the Extract To field. Click the Extract button.
- Enter these commands in a command prompt

  ```
  cd "C:\RubyDevKit"
  ruby dk.rb init
  ruby dk.rb install
  ```
- Close the command prompt window.

**Install `bundler`**

```
gem install bundler
```

**Download the source code for `BBYIDX`**

- Create a directory called `bbyidx` on `C` drive.
- [Download](https://github.com/BBYOpen/BBYIDX/zipball/master) the latest zipball of the project source code.
- Unzip the downloaded zip file to `c:\bbyidx` directory.

**Configure `config/environment_custom.rb`**

Set following parameter at minimum:

```
SESSION_SECRET = 'GIVE SOME LONG KEY HERE'
```

**Add `Postgres` gem to `gems` file**

Add the following text to the 3rd line of the file `c:\bbyidx\Gemfile`

```
gem 'pg'
```

**Install the required gems and create the required tables.**

```
bundle install
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

**Run the server**

```
ruby script/server
```

**Test the server**

Launch the browser and http://localhost:3000

**Reference**

1. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7133391/163203) for more details about configuring Postgres

Comment: I am starting to try it out now... Are you sure about the "script/server" command to run the server?

Comment: if it's Rails 3, instead of that script you start the server using rake

Comment: @Germstorm, the instructions are for Rails 2.3.x as BBYIDX doesnt support Rails 3. Here is what they say about this topic: `BBYIDX runs on Rails 2.3. It does not (yet) run on Rails 3. Don't worry about installing the correct version of Rails and all the gems and plugins; bundler should take care of all that automatically.`