# How to configure Postgresql with rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database-connection

I am very new to ruby. I am trying to run `BBYIDX` and followed [How to install BBYIDX on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640297/how-to-install-bbyidx-on-windows)

When I try `rake db:migrate` it reproduces error as

```
(in /home/virinchy/BBYIDX-2/BBYIDX-master)  
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/acts_as_tsearch/tasks,   vendor/plugins/acts_as_tsearch/tasks, vendor/plugins/delayed_job/tasks,   vendor/plugins/nested_scenarios/tasks, vendor/plugins/rails-authorization-plugin/tasks, and   vendor/plugins/rails_rcov/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)  
rake aborted!  
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "bbyidx"  
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "bbyidx"
Bundle install was succesful with message as:Your bundle is complete!  
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

But `rake db:migrate` produces this error. I am running `ubuntu 12.04`, `ruby-1.8.7`, `rails-2.3.11` and `gem 1.5.3`

How do i solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set a password for your `postgres` user?

In your `config/database.yml` you should have your databases set up properly:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: your_app_development # name your development app something
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: your_username
  password: your_password # or leave blank if you didn't set a password

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: your_app_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: your_username
  password: your_password
```

Comment: Here is my database.yml.# SQLite version 3.x
adapter: postgresql  
  database: bbyidx_dev  
  username: bbyidx  
  password: 123456  
  host: localhost

Comment: Did you try changing it like I've written? You can keep the names that you currently have obviously.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.I have followed [link](http://railskey.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/postgresql-installation-in-ubuntu-12-04/) to install postgresql in ubuntu12.04.

Comment: Here's my database.yml file.This Did n't make any change to it. [link](http://pastebin.com/DQAv3y4N)

Comment: Probably not, I've always had it though.

Comment: Do i need to configure any changes to postgresql?

Comment: Here's the the link of the [rake db:migrate--trace](http://pastebin.com/YF0EaCav)