# Connect PostgreSQL to HammerDB

Tags: postgresql, database-connection

As the title says, I want to connect PostgreSQL (I'm using the 9.6 x86 version) to [HammerDB](http://www.hammerdb.com/), an open source database load testing and benchmarking tool (I'm interested in the TPC-C Benchmark).

The thing is that I can do this connection by using MS SQL Server (2014), because it is relatively easy. However, I'm not used to use PostgreSQL. When I try to create Virtual Users on HammerDB (that's the 1st step to do, then you should be able to perform the transactions) I get the following error:

```
Error in Virtual User 1: Failed to load Pgtcl - Postgres Library Error
```

I did some research about this, and I found that, and I quote ["PostgreSQL is VERY particular about the libraries in its PATH - they have to be the right ones and ONLY the right ones any other configuration will cause errors"](https://sourceforge.net/p/hammerora/discussion/292313/thread/f0607d70/).

The problem is that HammerDB couldn't load library libpgtcl.dll. There they mention that to fix the problem, one should check that the PostgreSQL bin directory has been added to the path during install, but at this point I'm totally lost and I don't know what to do. I simply can´t get what they mean and how to do it.

I hope at least one of you could help me. I would appreciate it a lot.

Sorry in advance for my mistakes in English, I'm a Spanish speaker.

Comment: How did you install `PostgreSQL`? using binaries or graphical installer?

Comment: @chalithageekiyanage I used a graphical installer. And I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have solved the problem, and it is very simple.

Everything is about Setting Windows PATH for PostgreSQL, and I found that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460823/setting-windows-path-for-postgres-tools/22921860#22921860).

```
Open my Computer ==>
  right click inside my computer and select properties ==>
    Click on Advanced System Settings ==>
       Environment Variables ==>
          from the System Variables box select "PATH" ==>
             Edit... ==>
```

Then add this at the end of whatever you find their

```
 ;C:\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin; C:\PostgreSQL\9.2\lib
```

after that continue to click OK

That's all. So this is what you should do if you are having trouble when trying to connect PostgreSQL to HammerDB, and in general, when trying to use PostgreSQL tools.